# Determining whether a class is a parent or child in a SQLAlchemy relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a relationship attribute of a SQLAlchemy class, I want to determine whether it refers to a parent table (where the foreign key is in the other table), or to a child table (where the foreign key is in the current table).

For example, consider two classes `A` and `B` with relationships `A.bs` and `B.a`:

```
class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bs = relationship(B, backref='a')
```

In the `A.bs` relationship, A is the "parent" because the foreign key is in the other class. In the `B.a` relationship, B is the "child" because the foreign key is in the same class. If I had a function `is_parent` that did this, it would work like this:

```
is_parent(A.bs) == True
is_parent(B.a) == False
```

How can I use SQLAlchemy to implement something like the `is_parent` function?

Answer (score 0):

(Honestly, I can't quite imagine why you would want this, but it is more or less easy to solve looking at the structure of the class).

```
In [37]:

from sqlalchemy.orm.properties import ColumnProperty
from sqlalchemy.orm.relationships import RelationshipProperty 
​
def is_parent(obj):
    if type(obj.property) == ColumnProperty:
        return False
    if type(obj.property) == RelationshipProperty: 
        return True
    return None
​
print is_parent(B.a_id)
print is_parent(A.bs)

False
True
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't work because `A.bs` and `B.a` are both instances of `RelationshipProperty`. `B.a_id` is a `ColumnProperty` but I can't see how that would be used to figure out the direction of the `B.a` relationship.

Comment: Well, I tested it after running the code you provided, copy-paste, and for me it works... And when you define a relationship the pattern is exactly as you did, in the parent table you define the relationship, and in the child the column as a foreign key. I'm sure you know [this link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many). Anyway, you tested it and it does not work for you?

Comment: That code does work, but I am interested in `B.a` (the relationship defined via `backref`), not `B.a_id`.  (Also, a SQLAlchemy relationship does not necessarily have to be defined in the class corresponding to the parent table; I could also have written `b.a = relationship(A, backref='bs')`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the `B.a`. And I guess you're right, you could have written the relationship in the opposite way. Indeed, if you don't follow the pattern, my proposed solution does not work.